RSTP Loop Limitations
Recently ,i joined a new company and they assigned me to a under progress site actually it was a hotel with two 12 storey building merged as a single 12 storey building.They have done cabling as per their previous IT consultant.
Each storey has total 64 room ,so all the cables from 32 room(left side) are kept on a one server rack and remaining cables from 32 room(right side ) are kept on another rack.Each server rack would have switches where separate vlan would configured  for cctv,ip phone,access point(wifi),TV.
cctv-400(quantity)
Tv-312
Ip phone-700
wifi-300-400
floor cabling is done with lan cable and loop would be done with fibre link.
MY question is
1)was it good idea to run RSTP loop(on 24 swicthes) by placing l2 or l3 switches on each server rack?
2)DO RSTP loop have device limitation?
3)And please suggest me a better solution for this topology and protocol  along with device list that i should implement

You should not link switches in a line. Each switch should have a direct run down to the distribution switch(es). The normal way is to use fiber for the vertical cable between data closets, and use copper for the horizontal cable out to the workstations. Lines and loops should not be used, trees are what you should use.

Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.


was it good idea to run RSTP loop(on 24 switches) by placing l2 or l3 switches on each server rack?

No. You do need switches in each closet rack, but the design limit of modern STP - RSTP or MSTP - is seven hops. A network with a larger diameter is bound to never converge with default parameters. You could tweak STP parameters to stretch that design limit, at the cost of converge speed. See here for details.
The "natural" topology for bridged Ethernet is a tree. So, instead of creating a large ring you need to connect each story switch to the basement (core) switch directly. That topology also removes the bottlenecks of the lower-story links having to pass all traffic from the more higher up ones (with the assumed uplink in the basement).
If your cabling doesn't support a full tree you could chain groups of two or perhaps three stories as a compromise. If you're still in planning, vertical cabling should use fiber, with copper being limited to horizontal cabling only.
A more complex setup using routed links instead of simpler bridged links is also possible. Here, you'd use a routing protocol like OSPF instead of L2 redundancy with STP.

thanks @zac67 for your suggestion.If i connect each storey switch to basement switch seperately  with fibre connection for up link then, what can i do for  link failure so that link goes up automatically  incase of link failure ?

For link redundancy you could connect the storey switches in pairs. STP would block that extra link during normal operation.

MST (in non-fallback mode) can have a much greater diameter. (there's an actual TTL/Hop count in the protocol) STP/RSTP/PVST/etc. have a default diameter of 7, but can be tweaked to ~14. (but if you need to mess with it, you might want to find a better design.)

@Zac67 My total devices on sites are above 1000. Which set up would be better for this requirement l2 or l3?

@Sjn1238 The number of devices isn't really relevant. If there are multiple switches per enclosure then you could use one for uplink and chain the others, or connect each one to the core. Using L2 or L3 is a complex design decision, there's no simple 'better' setup.
